# division of exponentials that converges to linear function

Tags: limits, exponential-function

When experimenting in R code with the function
$$ f(\sigma^2) = \frac{ae^{-\frac{(a-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}-be^{-\frac{(b-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{e^{-\frac{(a-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}-e^{-\frac{(b-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$
for constant $a,b,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ with a<b and $\mu\neq\frac{a+b}{2}$, I noticed that $f(\sigma^2)$ converges to a linear function $g(\sigma^2)=k\sigma^2+d$ as $\sigma^2\to\infty$ for any  $a,b,\mu$ I tested. Note that $\sigma^2 > 0.$

**Question**: Can we prove this convergence for any valid $a,b,\mu$ and find the linear parameters $k$ and $d$?

My initial guess was that $k=\frac{1}{\mu-\frac{a+b}{2}}$ and $d=-(\frac{a+b}{2})$, which seems to be the solution, but I failed to come up with a solid proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a problem of limit.

Let $$2\sigma^2=\frac 1 \epsilon\quad \implies \quad f=\frac{a e^{-\epsilon  (a-\mu )^2}-b e^{-\epsilon  (b-\mu
   )^2}}{e^{-\epsilon  (a-\mu )^2}-e^{-\epsilon  (b-\mu )^2}}$$ Make a Taylor series around $\epsilon=0$ to get
$$f=\frac{1}{\epsilon  (2 \mu-(a+b) )}+\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{1}{12}
   \epsilon  \left((a-b)^2 (a+b-2 \mu )\right)+O\left(\epsilon
   ^3\right)$$
$$f=\frac{1}{\epsilon  (2 \mu-(a+b )})+\frac{a+b}{2}+O\left(\epsilon  \right)$$

Replace $\epsilon$ by $\frac 1{2\sigma^2}$.

Comment: [+1] Hi Claude. Very concise...

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thank you ! I cannot type too much. Are you OK ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Conciseness is important in our world where many things are diluted...

Comment: I agree at a level of $1000$%. By the way, do you know where *Blabla* is coming from ?

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea...

Comment: I checked with https://www.dcode.fr/developpement-limite. Quite surprising that there is indeed no term in $\epsilon^2.$

Comment: @JeanMarie. *Le canard enchaîné* during thé first World War* and thé word has been adopted in many langages. Isn't funny ?

Comment: Funny indeed ! I didn't know. I have been checking the (non completely) equivalent term "blah" : there are many funny "origins" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blah ... including the french "origin" "blasé'...

Answer (score 1):

(Nearly the same answer as Claude Lebovici: just some more computation-blabla and some less terms in the asymptotic approximation.)

Let $h=\frac1{2\sigma^2}\to0,$ $\alpha=a-\mu,$ and $\beta=b-\mu.$ Using $e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}2+o(t^2),$ we get
$$\begin{align}f&=\frac{(\alpha+\mu)e^{-\alpha^2h}-(\beta+\mu)e^{-\beta^2h}}{e^{-\alpha^2h}-e^{-\beta^2h}}\\&=\frac{(\alpha+\mu)(1-\alpha^2h)-(\beta+\mu)(1-\beta^2h)+o(h)}{(\beta^2-\alpha^2)h+\frac{\alpha^4-\beta^4}2h^2+o(h^2)}\\&=\frac{(\alpha-\beta)\left(1-h(\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2+\mu(\alpha+\beta)\right)+o(h)}{(\beta^2-\alpha^2)h\left
(1-\frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}2h+o(h)\right)}\\
&=\frac{-1}{h(\alpha+\beta)}\left(1-h\left(\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2+\mu(\alpha+\beta)-\frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}2\right)+o(h)\right)
\\&=\frac{-1}{h(\alpha+\beta)}+\frac{\alpha+\beta}2+\mu+o(1)
\\&=\frac1{h\left(2\mu-(a+b)\right)}+\frac{a+b}2+o(1).
\end{align}$$